# Don't charge to 100% when always-on wall-plugged-in

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging

I want to use a Google Nexus phone for an always-on wall-plugged-in WiFi tethering access station.

It occurred to me that if I just do it like this, then I'm risking ruining the battery within a couple of months, and the battery becoming useless, potentially leaving the phone permanently handicapped to a wall-plug operation, and within a year or two, going as far as requiring an external UPS for power-outage situations, too.

Is there a solution to start charging when below 40% or 50%, and stop charging at 60% to 80%?

Comment: Are there tablets that work without battery in, but plugged in to power?

Comment: @NoBugs, my phone that I'm currently using as my part-time access point does actually have a removable battery, but the whole point of the question is that you don't want to choose between having no UPS at all (whilst preserving the battery for potential future use by storing elsewhere at 40 to 50% charge), or ruining the battery within a year or so by not engaging in any conservation efforts, and then going back to having practically no UPS, too.

Comment: Thinking out loud here, could you use a pc and control the USB to charge for set times as a work around?

Comment: @RossC, ideally, I'd want to use a PC to not simply control to set times to charge-recharge the battery, but to provide only enough power through the USB for the phone to function, without much extra power to actually charge the battery.  If you know the tools, I actually already have such question for you: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63121/usb-host-to-disable-charging-for-an-always-on-usb-tethering

Comment: @RossC Unless you have a special usb controller you made for the purpose, no, the 5v is hard-soldered to the usbs.

Comment: @NoBugs, what about laptops and such?  Don't they have the ability to control how much power external devices get through USB?

Comment: Other than a BIOS setting for enabling/disabling usb charging while computer is off, I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you're needing it as always-on wall plugged you will probably need to stick with that. However newer devices stop charge when 100% and then recharge back from ~95%.

Answer here: [How to stop an android device from being charged programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654233/3288281) Says that you simply can't use any software to stop the charging.

Comment: That constant charging, discharging slightly and charging again will wreck the battery, even the heat overhead alone will do it. If the device has a removable battery you might as well, but a nexus is a no go. +1 for the link / info.

Comment: @RossC, I'm actually still using a Galaxy Nexus, which does have removable battery; however, removing the battery is a very ugly solution -- it means I either have to have an extra UPS, or forego internet connectivity when the power is out.  P.S. Actually, it just occurred to me that I could utilise a netbook's battery to go around the power-outages, however, the netbook itself also risks having its battery ruined due to a constant recharging to 100%: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114412/how-do-i-stop-charging-the-battery-way-prior-to-100-in-openbsd

Comment: Since it is removable you could buy a few spares and let them die over time? It's not at all ideal but just seeing what can be done.

Comment: Don't some ROMs have "rapid charge" feature you can turn on? Maybe there is something similar for limiting it?